# soql subquery in SELECT clause

Tags: soql

Can SOQL handle subqueries?  For example, to get the row counts of both current and deleted rows in a table..

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM SNF___c WHERE IsDeleted = False) is_deleted, 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM SNF___c WHERE IsDeleted = True) is_current
```

When I execute this in SSIS / TaskFactory SalesForce.Com Source component I receive the error message in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subqueries are possible but they are not aliasable nor can you select anything that isn't a "child" object of the main object you are selecting.  Example right from the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/):

```
SELECT Account.Name, (SELECT Contact.LastName FROM Account.Contacts)
FROM Account
```

Comment: Okay.  In that case I'll run these as separate queries, and merge the results.